# Value of arraylist keeps reseting in meny

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm going to try and explain this the best I can. In school we are making a program that allows you to choose if you want to make a array or a ArrayList then add numbers to them. That part is working fine.

The problem is in the meny you are also going to get the options to convert an array to ArrayList and the other way around. When I try to send in the array or arraylist to the class using a case switch, I get the error that I have not initialized. But if I set it to null to start with it, will just reset the users input the next time it starts the meny. So I'm wondering if there is a way to initialize the array and arraylist once, and then skip it the next time around? I know this is a bad explanation but if you look at the code maybe you understand what I'm trying to ask.

```
package labb;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Meny {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static boolean meny(Scanner input){

        Scanner inputMeny = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> arrayListNumbers = null;

        System.out.println("\n What do you want to do? \n 1 : Arraylist? \n 2 : Array? \n 3 : Convert your Array to an Arraylist \n 4 : Convert your Arraylist to an Array \n 5 : Exit");

        int answer = inputMeny.nextInt();

        switch(answer){
        case(1)://arrayList

           arrayListNumbers = Array.readNumbersFromUser(input);
           PrintNumbers.PrintOutNumbers(arrayListNumbers);
           System.out.println("\n");
           PrintNumbers.PrintOutNumbers2(arrayListNumbers);
           return true;

        case(2)://array

           int[] arrayNumbers = Array.readNumbersFromUserArray(input);
           PrintNumbers.printNumbersArray(arrayNumbers);
           System.out.println();
           PrintNumbers.printNumbers2Array(arrayNumbers);
           return true;

        case(3)://array to arrayList

        case(4)://arrayList to array

        int[] array = Convert.convertArrayListToArray(arrayListNumbers);

        case(5):
           System.out.println("Good bye");
           inputMeny.close();
           return false;

        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
            inputMeny.close();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> arrayListNumbers = null; This is your problem, you get a new arraylist everytime you call meny(scanner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of calling  public static boolean meny(Scanner input) call  public static boolean meny(Scanner input, ArrayList arrayListNumbers ). From the point where you call this method (meny), get the arrayListNumbers

so your code maybe could look like this

where you call the method

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListNumbers = Array.readNumbersFromUser(input);
meny.meny(input, arrayListNumbers );
```

and the class

```
public class Meny {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static boolean meny(Scanner input, ArrayList<Integer> arrayListNumbers){

        Scanner inputMeny = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("\n What do you want to do? \n 1 : Arraylist? \n 2 : Array? \n 3 : Convert your Array to an Arraylist \n 4 : Convert your Arraylist to an Array \n 5 : Exit");

        int answer = inputMeny.nextInt();
.....
```

Comment: thank you so much! This made everything work perfect with a little redesign of the other classes :)